# How to create an element in a HTML table that partially span cells

Tags: html, css

I would like to place `<div>` elements in a HTML table that partially span cells in the horizontal direction as shown in the figure below. For example, the top left red element spans the 2015, 2016, and 1/4 of 2017 cells. The code snippet below shows elements confined to a cell, however, I would like to know what is the best approach to extend them across multiple cells.

Note that I am only looking for HTML and CSS not JS.

[image: HTML table timeline]

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <colgroup>
       <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
    </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>2015</th>
    <th>2016</th> 
    <th>2017</th>
    <th>2018</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><div style="background: red; border:1px solid black; padding: 2px;">valid for</div></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><div style="background: red; border:1px solid black; padding: 2px;">valid for</divn></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><div style="background-color: blue; border:1px solid black; padding: 2px;">abc</div></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><div style="background-color: green; border:1px solid black; padding: 2px;">i have a tooltip with mouse over</div></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible with CSS alone, you'll need JS to calculate the span width. Share the code of what you have done so far.

Comment: without any code of yours (html data retrieved) and any of your attemps , there is no way to help you but do your job which is not what SO stands for. table might not even be what you need. display:grid might do the job here.

Comment: Sorry, let me simplify the question (pleased see edited). Only asking for example HTML and CSS that can display an element that crosses over cells and partially fills a cell. No JS.

Comment: absolute position will allow to lay over a few cells at once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the table only for the calendar grid and put all the "valid for"-bars in the first cell of the correspinding row. Give the table cells (TD) the position: relative style and the bars a position: absolute style. Now calculate and set the left and width styles for the bars accrding to the calendar.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; width: 100px">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 220px;">valid from</div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 280px; width: 120px;">valid from</div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px"></td>
    <td style="width: 100px"></td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to be one way. It would still be nice to do this relative to the cell and not the entire row. I would like to wait a few days to see if there are any other answers before marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could add the bars relative to the calendar cells of the year they start in. This would look something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; width: 100px">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 220px;">valid from</div>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px; position: relative"></td>
    <td style="width: 100px; position: relative">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 80px; width: 120px;">valid from</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```